# Can not install Spring Tool Suite under Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-tool-suite

I m trying to install Spring Tools Suite (STS) for Eclipse Juno (3.8 + 4.2) with the Eclipse MarketPlace, but when I m trying to install it, the installer said:

```
The following solutions are not available: Spring Tool Suite (STS) for Eclipse Juno (3.8 + 4.2) (id=org.springframework.ide.eclipse.mylyn.feature.feature.group, org.springframework.ide.eclipse.autowire.feature.feature.group, org.springframework.ide.eclipse.aop.feature.feature.group, org.springframework.ide.eclipse.ajdt.feature.feature.group, org.springframework.ide.eclipse.osgi.feature.feature.group, com.vmware.vfabric.ide.eclipse.tcserver.insight.feature.group, org.springframework.ide.eclipse.roo.feature.feature.group, org.springframework.ide.eclipse.security.feature.feature.group, org.springframework.ide.eclipse.webflow.feature.feature.group, org.springframework.ide.eclipse.batch.feature.feature.group, org.springframework.ide.eclipse.maven.feature.feature.group, org.springsource.ide.eclipse.dashboard.feature.group, org.springframework.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group, org.springframework.ide.eclipse.integration.feature.feature.group, org.springframework.ide.eclipse.data.feature.feature.group, org.springframework.ide.eclipse.uaa.feature.feature.group, site=http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.2/)
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: It was a problem on their side, but already repaired. I try install STS via Eclipse Marketplace today and it's worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you. Try the below link

[SpringSource Tool Suite for Eclipse Juno (4.2)](http://blog.springsource.org/2012/03/14/early-access-springsource-tool-suite-for-eclipse-juno-4-2/)

Comment: It doesn´t work for me, when I doing the third step I cant see STS on the selection items. What I finally did was install the complete app (not just install the plugin under Juno) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Open eclipse

1. Help --> Eclipse Marketplace
2. Search by keyword  "STS"
3. Click install button on "Spring Tool Suite (STS) for Eclipse Juno (3.8 + 4.2)" section
4. Follow the eclipse instruction

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to install the Spring Tool Suite into Eclipse and I too get the same error. If I go to [spring source downloads site](http://www.springsource.org/downloads/sts-ggts) and try download any of the releases, I also get errors. It seems their downloads site is currently down...

Regards,
PM.

Comment: It is looking like a possible DNS problem at the moment. See [springsource forum thread](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?133411-Cannot-download-STS-Download-site-is-down)